# Caching data returned from Shopware6 API's

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

To avoid recurring DB calls for data that could be cached im looking for a method to cache returned data in shopware 6. Does shopware already provide a cache or do we have to use symfony cache extension towards a redis or the likes?

Kr Ole

Searched the shopware documentation without finding a good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shopware comes with different layers of caching out of the box, you can find information on how to activate them and how you can configure them in the [official docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/performance/caches).

Keep in mind that most of the caches are optimized for the Store-API/Storefront, so in general requests to the Admin-API are not cached.

Comment: Hi j_elfering we are syncing loads of products in the system with sync api and want to cache the data on manufatures list, some rules fetched and stuff. This means that we are looking for some sort of in memory cache while syncing the products.

Comment: That is currently not done by shopware itself, so i would advice you to implement it yourself via the symfony/cache component